# table does not exits in the engine.

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

Due to system crash, phpmyadmin tells me that "#1992 table doesn't exits in engine". I have imported create_table.sql  file to recreate phpmyadmin database, but failed. I am using xampp v3.2.2 on windows with 10.1.13-MariaDB.

Comment: Can you query mysql via a client or command line. Check if the table really exist with something like  select * from  SELECT table_name, table_type, engin FROM information_schema.tables  where blah blah.....    https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html

Comment: table is there, table_type=BASE TABLE , engine =null and other column are null too.

Comment: refresh, rebuild.. not sure how phpmyadmin does that...any logs?

Comment: 2017-05-28 10:50:13 149c InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "xxxx"."user_vehicles" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html